# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field when creating a singleton Manager

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class GameManager {
    private static GameManager INSTANCE;

    private final int INITIAL_SCORE = 0;

    private int mCurrentScore;

    GameManager(){
    }

    public static GameManager getInstance(){
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = new GameManager();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public int getCurrentScore(){
        return mCurrentScore;
    }

    public void incrementScore(int pIncrementBy){
        mCurrentScore += pIncrementBy;
    }

    public void resetGame(){
        mCurrentScore = GameManager.INITIAL_SCORE;
    }
}
```

I run the above code in eclipse. 
I'd like to know why eclipse told me "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field GameManager.INITIAL_SCORE" when assigning the value of GameManager.INITIAL_SCORE to that of mCurrentScore. mCurrentScore is not static, is it? If mCurrentScore is not static, why should I declare INITIAL_SCORE as static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you prefix a variable with a class name you are telling Java the variable is static.  Since the variable is not static it is giving you an error.  The code should read:

```
public void resetGame(){
    mCurrentScore = INITIAL_SCORE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me Java's rule. I didn't know that until I saw your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private final int INITIAL_SCORE = 0;
```

is not `static` field, it is instance field (which is same like `mCurrentScore`). You need to just return INITIAL_SCORE;

You can't access it is using Class name.